# WordPress: how to use non-ugly permalinks without access to .htaccess?

Tags: hosting, wordpress

I'm new to blog hosting etc, so this may be an ultra-newbie question.

I just started my own blog, using WordPress.org, hosted by MyDomain/NamesDirect. I would like to use permalinks (nothing fancy, the suggested `/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/` will do just fine). However, I do not have access to the .htaccess files. I have (if I understand correctly) Linux hosting with Apache.

I approached MyDomain's support and they answered as follows:

```
Hello,

We unfortunately do not give access to the .htaccess file when you install it
through our apps server. 

You would have to use it from another party.
```

To clarify - as long as I use "ugly" permalinks (e.g. http://mysite.com/?p=123) everything works fine.

What can I do besides switching my hosting service?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PATHINFO. Choose custom structure and put `index.php/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/` instead of `/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/`. Of course URL will start with index.php
See [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) for more information on how it works

Comment: Thanks, it works. Does it have any negative SEO effect?

Comment: Good question. I just don't know. With google I found that blog.taragana.com is using PATHINFO and by searching site:blog.taragana.com inurl:index.php you can see that page are correctily indexed but I don't know if without index.php in the path they would have a better PageRank